# Python tkinter label is adding an extra digit to a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI for a board game. My game logic counts the pieces of both the black and white colors and returns the amount. In the GUI I use 2 pairs of labels to display the info.

```
self._white_score_label = tkinter.Label(
            master = self._info_frame, text = 'White:', font = default_font)

        self._white_score_label.grid(
            row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10,
            sticky = tkinter.E)

        self._white_score_num = tkinter.Label(
            master = self._info_frame, text = str(self._white_count), font = default_font)

        self._white_score_num.grid(
            row = 0, column = 1, padx = 0, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.W) 

        self._black_score_label = tkinter.Label(
            master = self._info_frame, text = 'Black:', font = default_font)

        self._black_score_label.grid(
            row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.E)


        self._black_score_num = tkinter.Label(
            master = self._info_frame, text = str(self._black_count), font = default_font)

        self._black_score_num.grid(
            row = 1, column = 1, padx = 0, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.W)
```

The problem is when one count has a two-digit string and the other one-digit string then the one-digit string gets a random number added to it. [HERE](http://gyazo.com/d38662cb0be5e7adbdb76c9b9363882a) is a screenshot. The shell shows that the count functions are correct, showing a 9 and 16. However the label is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That digit `2` was there before you printed `9`. May the score was `12` or `22` before, then it became `9`, and you printed `9` on top of `12`, `9` was painted over `1`, but `2` remained. One way to fix it would be to draw a rectangle over that area before rendering a label, or rendering several spaces after the score. But the correct way would probably be to reuse the same label every time you render the score, and change its text, instead of creating a new label every time.